# Visual Studio 2008 Deprecated method

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I used to get warning message when I use deprecated methods in c#/vb.net.  Now the compiler never warns me about it. I even created a new solution and project and still the same. Is there a visual studio setting that causes the compiler to suppress warning messages?

Answer (score 3):

There is indeed a project setting for warning messages.

It can be found in your project properties, in the "Build" tab, under the "Errors and warnings" section.

Comment: I checked there but still same.

Comment: Hmm... Only other thing I know that can disable warnings is the #pragma warning preprocessor directive.

Are you sure you have "Warnings" checked (or clicked) in the Error list window ?

Comment: yes i am sure.. weird thing is i got the obsolete warnings, but not the deprecated function warnings..